# Refreshing Spark Properties on a Running Streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to update the spark properties of a currently running spark streaming job.

I have set some properties on SparkConf in the programs and some on spark-defaults.conf.

How do i update them so that my curently running job will pick them?

Is it possible to do like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is not possible to refresh configuration during runtime. Only certain SQL options can be changed with active context.

Otherwise:

- modify configuration
- restart app